# How do i make the bubblesort sort the list shoes by using itemsellingprice

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
class Shoe:
def __init__(self,itemname,itemindex,description,itemsellingprice,itemstocklevel,itemtype):
    self.__itemname = itemname
    self.__itemindex = itemindex
    self.__description = description
    self.__itemsellingprice = itemsellingprice
    self.__itemstocklevel = itemstocklevel
    self.__itemtype = itemtype

def get_itemname(self):
    return self.__itemname
def get_itemindex(self):
    return self.__itemindex
def get_description(self):
    return self.__description
def get_itemsellingprice(self):
    return self.__itemsellingprice
def get_itemstocklevel(self):
    return self.__itemstocklevel
def get_itemtype(self):
    return self.__itemtype

def set_itemname(self,itemname):
    self.__itemname = itemname
def set_itemindex(self,itemindex):
    self.__itemindex = itemindex
def set_description(self,description):
    self.__description = description
def set_itemsellingprice(self,itemsellingprice):
    self.__itemsellingprice = itemsellingprice
def set_itemstocklevel(self,itemstocklevel):
    self.__itemstocklevel = itemstocklevel
def set_itemtype(self,itemtype):
    self.__itemtype = itemtype


def __str__(self):
    return "{} (Item Index = {} ) Item Description: {},it is also a {} type shoe worth {}. There is currently {} in stock".format(self.__itemname,self.__itemindex,self.__description,self.__itemtype,self.__itemsellingprice,self.__itemstocklevel)


def add():
itemindex = 0
itemname = input("Enter shoe's name: ")
description = input("Please enter shoe's description: ")
itemsellingprice = int(input("Please enter shoe's selling price: "))
itemstocklevel = int(input("Please enter shoe's stock level: "))
itemtype = input("Please enter shoe type: ")

shoeitem = Shoe.Shoe(itemname,itemindex,description, itemsellingprice, itemstocklevel, itemtype)
shoes.append(shoeitem)

print("Shoe Successfully Added")
itemindex += 1
```

This is the add function

def bubblesort(shoes):
n = len(shoes)

```
for i in range(n - 1 , 0 ,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        if shoes[j] > shoes[j + 1]:
            tmp = shoes[j]
            shoes[j] = shoes[j + 1]
            shoes[j + 1] = tmp

for i in range(len(shoes)):
    print("% d" % shoes[i])

print(bubblesort(shoes))
```

I want the bubblesort when i add objects into the list shoes to sort out the list by using the itemsellingprice attribute in shoes. I'm guessing it has something to do with replacing the shoes[j] with something that calls the value of itemsellingprice.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: edit the bubble-sort code

In your bubble-sort code, you have the line:

```py
if shoes[j] > shoes[j + 1]:
```

You could modify that condition for a more explicit condition which compares the selling prices.

```py
if shoes[j].get_itemsellingprice() > shoes[j + 1].get_itemsellingprice():
```

## Solution 2: modify the `Shoe` class

Since `Shoe` is a class, you can implement comparison operators yourself, to supersede the default behaviour of `<` and `<=`.

```py
class Shoe:
  # ...
  
  def __le__(self, other):
    return self.get_itemsellingprice() <= other.get_itemsellingprice()

  def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.get_itemsellingprice() < other.get_itemsellingprice()
```

The two member functions `.__le__` and `.__lt__` play a special role; Python will recognize that you are implementing a special comparison for the `Shoe` class; when you compare two Shoe objects in the bubble-sort code, Python will use the member functions `.__le__` or `.__lt__`.